# Why are two different hashes being generated for the same subStrings and what can I do to solve this?

Tags: java, math, hash, rabin-karp

I wrote the following code to try a simplistic implementation of the Rabin-Karp algorithm.

```
 public int charToInt(int index, String str){
        return (int)str.charAt(index);
    }

    public int strStr(String haystack, String needle) {
        if(needle.length() == 0 ) return 0;
        int n = needle.length();
        int l = haystack.length();
        if(n > l) return -1;

        //choose large enough prime for hash
        final int prime = 257;

        //calculate reference hash of needle and first 'n' chars of haystack
        long refHash = 0, rollHash = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            refHash += charToInt(i,needle)*(long)Math.pow(prime,i);
            rollHash += charToInt(i,haystack)*(long)Math.pow(prime,i);
        }
        System.out.println("refHash: "+refHash);
        System.out.println("rolling hash: "+rollHash);
        if(refHash == rollHash) return 0;

        for(int i = n; i<l; i++){
            // oldhash - old initial char
            rollHash -= charToInt(i-n+1, haystack);
            // divide by prime.
            System.out.println("Perfect division anticipated "+ (double)rollHash/prime);
            rollHash /= prime;
            // add new char to hash at the end of pattern.
            rollHash += (charToInt(i,haystack)*(long)Math.pow(prime,n-1));

            if(refHash == rollHash) return i-n+2;
            System.out.println("rolling hash: "+rollHash);
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Calculating the rolling hash like in the code above works well on paper but I am not able to figure out why `rollHash /= prime;` is not producing a perfect division.

An example input/output to hopefully provide more context.
Input

```
haystack: "hello"
needle: "ll"
```

Output

```
stdout:
refHash: 27864
rolling hash: 26061
Perfect division anticipated 101.01167315175097
rolling hash: 27857
Perfect division anticipated 107.9727626459144
rolling hash: 27863
Perfect division anticipated 107.99610894941634
rolling hash: 28634
Answer:
-1
```

What I hoped for was that `Perfect division anticipated 107.9727626459144` this line would output 108 and `rolling hash: 27863` the rolling hash would then be 27864.

Answer (score 0):

Lets think about the structure of `rollHash`. Let `A[]` be any array of the char values of `needle`. After the first loop `rollHash` will be

```
A[0] + prime * A[1] + prime^2 * A[2] + ...
```

In the second loop

```
for(int i = n; i<l; i++){
        // oldhash - old initial char
        rollHash -= charToInt(i-n+1, haystack);
        // divide by prime.
        System.out.println("Perfect division anticipated "+ (double)rollHash/prime);
        rollHash /= prime;
        ....
}
```

In the first iteration i = n and we subtract A[i-n+1] = A[1]. So `rollhash` is now

```
A[0] + prime * A[1] + prime^2 * A[2] + ... - A[1]
```

we would not expect this to be divisible by prime.

I think you have an off by one error.

```
for(int i = n; i<l; i++){
        // oldhash - old initial char
        rollHash -= charToInt(i-n, haystack);    // **** changed
        // divide by prime.
        System.out.println("Perfect division anticipated "+ (double)rollHash/prime);
        rollHash /= prime;
        ....
}
```

This now give perfect divisions and the algorithm seems to give the right results on limited test data.

Also note `Math.pow(i,j)` is a relatively expensive function and its quite easy to eliminate its use.